# How to show all Blogger comments (not just links) on a page?

Tags: blogger, comments

Is there a template or way to have full comments show on the blog, rather than having a link to them? I'd like for readers to see all the comments at once and be able to scroll down to review them. Possible?

Answer (score 3):

Under Settings > Posts, Comments and Sharing > Comments ... set Comment Location to Embedded.

NB   This certainly works on several of my blogs - I'm not sure if it functions the same way on all templates, though.